# Merging smaller boxes into larger boxes in a 2D grid

Tags: 2d, algorithm

Imagine a 2D Grid of boxes, each box is a square, like a chessboard.

Each box can be marked or unmarked depending on player actions.

I want to find an algorithm that groups marked boxes neighbouring each other into a larger boxes, resulting in the smaller amount of boxes possible.

Box grid:

[image: Box grid]

Marked boxes:

[image: Marked boxes]

Merged larger boxes:

[image: Merged larger boxes]

Comment: I've linked this question to [past Q&A we have about such algorithms](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/129648/39518). Please feel free to make edits if you need something distinct from what's addressed in the existing threads.

Comment: I've integrated your comment into the question. As DMGregory said, if you still think you can't figure this out with the help of the other question, you may edit this question further.